# How can we find the site logo for a Site programmatically

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, graphical-logo

The site-logo appears from the theme using the code in `portal_normal.vm`:

```
<img alt="$logo_description" height="$site_logo_height" src="$site_logo" width="$site_logo_width" />
```

I want to know the value of the variable `$site_logo` in my custom plugin portlet.

I am showing all the sites in a list and want to show the different logos for public and private pages besides the site-name.

Any pointers would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, liferay shows image logo from ThemeDisplay object.

I tried looking at [`ServicePreAction.java`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/events/ServicePreAction.java#L542) where `themeDisplay` object gets prepared, I found below things that would be helpful to you.

Using code below you can get `logourl` for any Site's Public or Private pages which you can set to html image tag.

```java
LayoutSet siblingLayoutSet = LayoutSetLocalServiceUtil.getLayoutSet(
                                groupId, isPrivatePages);

if (siblingLayoutSet.isLogo()) {
    logoId = siblingLayoutSet.getLogoId();
}

StringBundler sb = new StringBundler(5);
String imagePath=PortalUtil.getPathImage();
sb.append(imagePath);
sb.append("/layout_set_logo?img_id=");
sb.append(logoId);
sb.append("&t=");
sb.append(WebServerServletTokenUtil.getToken(logoId));

layoutSetLogo = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler way:

```
String logoPath = PortalUtil.getPortalURL(themeDisplay) + themeDisplay.getLayoutSetLogo();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Liferay 7.3.1. If you want to use the uploaded logo (public pages -> logo) in your theme, do the following:

in `templates/init_custom.ftl` (If you don't have this file, create it)

```
<#assign logo_img_path = themeDisplay.getLayoutSetLogo()/>
```

in `header.ftl` or whatever your file is add

```
<img
    src="${logo_img_path}"
    alt="My logo"
    title="My site"
/>
```

I provided this answer,because someone may found useful.